# Data not save in the database table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, data-persistence

I created sample java project and try to save data with JPA. able to connect with the database as well as able to create the related database table(named `laptop`) as well as. But when i try to save data(`Laptop` object). Those data not in the database table(in `laptop` table)

persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="laptop_persist">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/device_store"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="19940306"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Laptop.java class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Entity
@Table(name = "laptop")
public class Laptop implements Device {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long lapId;
    @Column(name = "brand_name")
    private String brandName;
    @Column(name = "model_name")
    private String modelName;
    @Column(name = "serial_number")
    private String serialNumber;

    public Laptop(String brandName, String modelName, String serialNumber) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.modelName = modelName;
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public Laptop() {
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public String getSerialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public Long getLapId() {
        return lapId;
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting the" + serialNumber + " laptop...");
    }

    public void restart() {
        System.out.println("restarting the laptop...");
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("Shutting down the laptop...");
    }
}
```

Main.java class

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Laptop laptop = new Laptop("aaa","bbb","cccc");
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("laptop_persist");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(laptop);
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>pc-hi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Archetype - pc-hi</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.31</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>8</source>
        <target>8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

As I mentioned in above, the `laptop` table has created. But unable to save the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you turn off auto-commit (i.e `hibernate.connection.autocommit=false`) which is a good practise for changing the data , you have to explicitly declare when to start and commit the transaction.

Change to the following should fix the issue :

```java
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(laptop);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```